# What is the difference between the center of mass energy of partons, and the invariant mass of the particles after a collision?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering-cross-section, invariants

In a paper about the Atlas experiment (https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.01918) differential cross sections of $pp→ZZ→4\ell$
are being presented. However these cross-sections are functions of the invariant mass $m_{4\ell}$. My question: Isn't the invariant mass basically constrained due to the center of mass energy of protons being $\sqrt{s}=13$TeV? How is it possible for the differential cross section to be represented as a function of $m_{4\ell}$, if $\sqrt{s}$ is fixed? On the other hand, is it possible to calculate the invariant phase space w.r.t. $m_{4\ell}$ theoretically, or is it something purely empirical?

Comment: At relativistic energies of the experiment, the Lorenz transformation algebra  defines the invariant mass, which is not the center of mass energy of the protons. If you really want to understand this, try http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Comment: @annav Thank you for your answer. I do understand this, however, according to the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass#As_defined_in_particle_physics, the invariant mass of a system of particles is defined as $M^2=(E_1+\ldots+E_n)^2-\|{\vec{p_1}+\ldots+\vec{p_n}}\|^2$, which reduces to $M^2=(E_1^\prime+\ldots+E_n^\prime)^2$ in the center of mass frame. If I understood correctly, this also equals to $s$, the center of mass energy of the system, which is fixed in the paper I mentioned in the question.

Comment: The formulae you suggest are not accurate for particle interactions, as pp scattering, it is not a system of particles but two protons that scatter off each other with virtual exchanges  between the  proton constituents.

Comment: see how QCD enters with all its complexities in the review https://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C060717/lec_notes/stirling_all.pdf